# How can I fix the error of installing Realm for swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift2, realm

I've try to install realm for swift 2.0, but error shown.
Please tell me how to solve this problem.
I've already done "sudo gem update cocoa pods", and "sudo gem install cocoapods --pre".

```
/Users/*******/App/BandApp% pod --version
0.36.4
/Users/*******/App/BandApp% cat Podfile
use_frameworks!
pod 'Realm', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
/Users/*******/App/BandApp% pod install 
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.39.0.beta.4 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Pre-downloading: `Realm` from `https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git`, branch `swift-2.0`

[!] Invalid `Realm.podspec` file: undefined method `module_map=' for #<Pod::Specification name="Realm">. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

 #  from /Users/*******/BandApp/Pods/Realm/Realm.podspec:38
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    s.module_map              = 'Realm/module.modulemap'
 #    s.compiler_flags          = "-DREALM_HAVE_CONFIG -DREALM_COCOA_VERSION='@\"#{s.version}\"' -D__ASSERTMACROS__"
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to update to CocoaPods 0.38.3.

Comment: Thank u so much!!
I've succeed.